# Can't find a way to tweak css of the "React Lazy Load Image Component"

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, lazy-loading

I am referring to the [React Lazy Load Image Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load-image-component).

I need to tweak the `display` attribute of the image I am rendering with this library. But can't seem to find any way.

I tried to wrap the component with a div and use `style={{display: 'inline'}}`, but it didn't work.

```
<div className="ui image" style={{ display: 'inline' }}>
       <LazyLoadImage 
             src={src}
             effect="blur"
       />
</div>
```

I am using this portion of code inside a `<Card/>` component. The default css of the library contains `display: inline-block` which is making my image have an extra border at the bottom. I don't want it.

**P.S.**

I am using `Semantic UI` for my entire project. I want to use whatever style Semantic is providing me. That's why I need to teak the `display` attribute of this library.

Comment: Note that this question is really "I need to do X, but I don't see how to do that in the documentation, does anyone know how to do this?", and asking that here is not going to be as helpful as asking the people who maintain the documentation. Please also post a docs update request over on https://github.com/Aljullu/react-lazy-load-image-component/issues to make sure the people who make this component add the information you needed, but couldn't find, to their readme. That way _everyone_ benefits.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I found the solution to there.

In case someone tries to make a new question about it again, here's the link to the issue where I found my solution: https://github.com/Aljullu/react-lazy-load-image-component/issues/33

Comment: That issue, is from almost half a year ago though, so you probably want to ask whether it's still in the works or not. A PR that never lands isn't _technically_ a solution =)